# What is the default ARP cache timeout for Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, cache, timeout, arp

All I can find for the default time an ARP entry remains in the cache before being removed for any Windows is all the way back from Windows 2000 or XP. It seems like 10 minutes is common for Windows, but I would like a confirmation for Windows 10. Where might this information be located?

Comment: The following page shows the timeout values for the new implementation since Windows Vista (random value between 15 and 45 seconds). I expect this is kept the same ever since. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/949589/description-of-address-resolution-protocol-arp-caching-behavior-in-win